# Why is Unity Dash showing the Desktop under "Downloads"?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

In the Unity Dash, when I click "Find Files", it has two sections: "Downloads" and "Favorite Folders", but the "Downloads" section is showing files from the desktop instead of "~/Downloads", which is where Chrome downloads files by default.

Is there any way to change what shows up there? It seems like the actual Downloads directory would be a lot more useful.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Please report this (if you are still experiencing this issue) on Launchpad.net - for more on reporting a bug, please take a look at this question.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try checking in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` directory and see if `XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR` is correctly set there.

Comment: I've switched to GNOME Shell since I asked this question so it's a non-issue now, but that was the problem, so thanks.